# Angularjs interceptor: Interceptor in not work

Tags: angularjs

Hi this below is my code from angularjs
The first part of the code shows exactly how I make the request to php which returns me data when there is code with an error when there is a problem.
When it returns me an error code, for example 401, the frontend explodes with an error and everything breaks.
As far as I understand, I have to use an interceptor so that I can catch the error number and not make an error.
I can't do this interception.

```
 app.js

    app.factory('httpRequester', function ($http, $route) {
    
        var promise;
        var myService = {
            async: function (myData) {
    
    //Create my obj for request
                var req = {
                    method: myData.Method,
                    url: 'https://**********/' + url,
                    headers: {
                        'X-API-KEY': '**************',
                        'KEY': myData.Authentication.AccessToken
                    },
                    data: myData
    
                };
    
    
                promise = $http(req).then(function (response) {
    
        if (response.data === 'permission denied') {
    
                        window.location.href = '#/';
                    } else {
                        return response;
                    }
                });
    
                return promise;
            }
        };
    
        return myService;
    });
```

//set interceptor in app.js
var interceptorApp = angular.module('interceptorApp', []);

```
interceptorApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('genericInterceptor');
});
```

Please help me with my problem, how to set interceptor work.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Function  for set error and success after request
    var testInterceptor = function ($q)  
    {  
        return {  
            request: function (config)  
            {  
                //console.log('request started...');  
            },  
            requestError: function (rejection)  
            {  
                console.log(rejection);  
                // Contains the data about the error on the request and return the promise rejection.    
                return $q.reject(rejection);  
            },  
            response: function (result)  
            {  
               // console.log('data for ' + result.data.name + ' received');  
                //If some manipulation of result is required before assigning to scope.    
                result["testKey"] = 'testValue';  
                console.log('request completed');  
                return result;  
            },  
            responseError: function (response)  
            {  
               // console.log('response error started...');  
                //Check different response status and do the necessary actions 400, 401, 403,401, or 500 eror     
                return $q.reject(response);  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).